# Find all possible path from source to destination in udirected graph

Tags: java, android, algorithm, graph

I am making a Android Bus App ,in that i have to find all possible path between source and destination. i am using dijkstra Algorithm with dfs search.

but when i entered source and destination for finding result ,it takeing more time and my app will crash.

please provide a solution ..

Comment: finding all paths in a general graph is impossible, there could be infinite number of those if the graph has cycles. Finding all *simple paths* is possible, there are finite number of those - but the number of simple paths is exponential in the number of nodes - so it will take a huge amount of time for a graph bigger than ~15-20 nodes.

Comment: Also, without the code - determining why you 'crash' is impossible. My guess is you are using a DFS without a visited set (because you want all paths) - which makes your stack explode, and depending on the implementation - you get a stack-overflow or out of memory. But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is crashing as, I believe, the algorithm you are using for finding a path where only one such path exists. Look up Kruskals for an algorithm that can find multiple paths.

https://github.com/monmohan/mgraphlib

may help

Comment: Kruskal algotithm finds a spanning **tree**. A tree has exactly one (simple) path between each pair of nodes. Not to mention the answer does not answer the issue with infinite number of paths between two nodes..

Comment: ok I realised that after posting. There are algorithms to find multiple paths just can't remember names. I don't think infinite is right either though as finite number of nodes will have finite number of paths. He will need to cut the search down some how. Blind alley filler/sealer find multiple paths

Comment: No, infinite number of nodes means there are finite number of *simple paths* - if the graph has cycles - you can iterate the cycle as many times as you want, and it will be a new (non simple) path. This is similar to the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma) from the field of formal languages.

Comment: My problem is that in my graph each bus stop lie on multiple line(ex:xyz(stop name) lie on route (A,B,C) number) so its taking more time here is my code: